# DataBinding from Views to other View

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a custom template for a ListView in Xamarin.Forms. Inside the template i put a custom view which has a property named "MainTemplate" which input is a template too. The problem is that if MainTemplate contains one or more DataBindings they are ignored (all the XAML is loaded, but bound data are skypped). Il looks like inside my template the scope gets lost.

The listView:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <c:GestureListItem>
                            <c:GestureListItem.MainTemplate>
                                <ContentView BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="10">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </ContentView>
                            </c:GestureListItem.MainTemplate>
                        </c:GestureListItem>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

My custom template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Xamtools.GestureListItem">
    <ContentView Content="{Binding MainTemplate}" x:Name="mainTemplate" />
</Grid>
```

...and its code behind:

```
public partial class GestureListItem : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MainTemplate", typeof(View), typeof(GestureListItem), null, propertyChanged: MainTemplatePropertyChanged);
    private static void MainTemplatePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var ob = bindable as GestureListItem;
        ob.MainTemplate = (View)newValue;
    }

    public View MainTemplate { set { SetValue(MainTemplateProperty, value); } get { return (View)GetValue(MainTemplateProperty); } }
    public GestureListItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainTemplate.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is something called  [DataTemplateSelector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector/)